# I deploy the maven package to jcenter successly,but when i use this package on another projects,it give me an error

Tags: java, maven, maven-deploy-plugin

As title, I deploy the package to jcenter successly,this is my pom.xml .

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.bloodnighttw.JDAwP</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDAwP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0_6</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <name>JDAwP</name>

<distributionManagement>
    <repository>
        <id>bintray-bloodnighttw-JDAwP</id>
        <name>bloodnighttw-JDAwP</name>
        <url>https://api.bintray.com/maven/bloodnighttw/JDAwP/JDAwP/;publish=1</url>
    </repository>
</distributionManagement>


    <repositories>

        <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
        </repository>

    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.6</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.dv8tion</groupId>
            <artifactId>JDA</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.1_104</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.3</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>    
    <plugins>

    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                  <goal>shade</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                  <shadedArtifactAttached>true</shadedArtifactAttached>
                  <shadedClassifierName></shadedClassifierName> <!-- Any name that makes sense -->
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>

     </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

So i run `mvn deploy` ,it deploy successly.(this is my [source code](https://github.com/bloodnighttw/JDAwP))

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  01:00 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-11T18:56:26+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

And i want to use this package in another project.
So i add something into my another project's pom.xml.
This is my "Another Project's" pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.github.bloodnighttw</groupId>
    <artifactId>Another-Projects</artifactId>
    <version>0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <repositories>
    <repository>
            <id>jcenter</id>
            <name>jcenter-bintray</name>
            <url>https://jcenter.bintray.com</url>
    </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
         <groupId>io.github.bloodnighttw.JDAwP</groupId>
        <artifactId>JDAwP</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0_5</version>
        <type>pom</type>
    </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>

      <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>8</source>
                    <target>8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

There is only a class in my projects(locate in /src/main/java/)
It is "Main.java", And the code of this file is that:

```
import io.github.*;

public class Main{
    //nothing here
}
```

And I run `mvn install` , I got this error!

```
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  8.212 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-02-11T18:49:06+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project Another-Projects: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /home/bbeenn1227/桌面/testMaven/src/main/java/Main.java:[1,1] package io.github does not exist
```

(By the way,I pretty sure that i have package "io.github.*")

I keep google a solution in this week,but I can't find any answer how to solve it.
So I decided to post a question on stackoverflow.
If you think my question is so stupid,just give me a little information about how to deal with it.

(And sorry about my bad english)

Comment: Please replace the linked image by a copy the relevant text.

Comment: Ok i will  edit it

Comment: Why are you using 7-year-old [maven-compiler-plugin](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-compiler-plugin)?

Comment: (My english is bad.)
Because my IDE will get some error after maven projects adding(chnaging).
To add this maven-compiler-plugin will avoid this error

Answer (score 0):

The dependency should probably be

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bloodnighttw.JDAwP</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDAwP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0_5</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>io.github.bloodnighttw.JDAwP</groupId>
    <artifactId>JDAwP</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0_5</version>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: So does your dependency include a package named `io.github`?

Comment: no ,but my project has a package name `` io.guthub ``

Comment: The error is `package io.github does not exist` so you probably do not have a package `io.github`. Note that the `groupId` has nothing to do with the package.

Comment: Ok,i see.And i have a question .

Comment: did my forward project 's pom.xml has something wrong?

Comment: maybe the problem is on deploy.